# How to disable CSS in asp.net for some pages

Tags: asp.net, css

I have downloaded and customized an opensource project, but after I plug it in with my login page, it looks strange. How can I disable CSS for some pages such as login page? I cannot edit or remove my CSS file because it will effect on my core system.

I am using asp.net with C#.

Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `css` under `Asp:Literal`or `Asp:PlaceHolder`

That way you can set its visibility on the page via

```
 MyPlaceHolder.Visible=CheckIftoSetForthisPage()
```

Comment: Does my css mean my customized css? I just want my login page to be in plain form without any format.

Comment: then put your login page css under the `Asp:PlaceHolder`